# Cypress intercept for dynamic pathParam in api and * functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I have few API's that i need to intercept.

```
'randomApi/import/entity'
'randomApi/import/entity/lead1/tabs'
'randomApi/import/entity/lead2/tabs'
```

**lead1** and **lead2** are values that are coming in the 1st api, so the values can be anything.

I was able to intercept the 1st one but not getting a proper solution for second and third one.

```
cy.intercept({
            pathname: '/randomApi/import/entity'
        }).as("entitiesData")
```

Also can anyone explain how does **`*`** and **`**`** work in these

```
1. cy.intercept({ pathname: '/randomApi/import/entity*'}).as("entitiesData")
2. cy.intercept({ pathname: '/randomApi/import/entity**'}).as("entitiesData")
3. cy.intercept({ pathname: '/randomApi/import/entity/*'}).as("entitiesData")
4. cy.intercept({ pathname: '/randomApi/import/entity/**'}).as("entitiesData")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcards go between path separators. Try this:

```js
cy.intercept('**/randomApi/import/entity/*/tabs', {}).as('leads')

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('https://my-host/randomApi/import/entity/lead1/tabs')
})

cy.wait('@leads')   // passes
```

Double stars asterisks are for multiple path sections, for example

```js
cy.intercept('**/randomApi/import/entity/**/tabs', {}).as('leads')

cy.window().then(win => {
  win.fetch('https://my-host/randomApi/import/entity/leads/lead1/tabs')
})

cy.wait('@leads')   // passes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. 
Another question though. I have added success and fail popup for the api, and i am writing intercept in beforeEach, so how can i write tests for both success and failure popup as i can modify the response for only one scenario